# URL causing javascript to disable

Tags: redirect

I have a website built in Magento.  Normally javascript runs fine, but someone pinned a product to pinterest and the URL they pinned appended a series of characters that for some reason causes the javascript to stop running on that page.  Here's the normal URL:

http://trumpetandhorn.com/vintage-engagement-rings/tiara-i.html

Here's the one that was pinned:

http://www.trumpetandhorn.com/vintage-engagement-rings/tiara-i.html#.UWC7Hb8fpFI

I've tried redirecting using htaccess but have had no luck with that.  It's important for us to fix this as the person who pinned the product has 2.7 million followers so we're seeing a ton of site traffic from this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please note that we don't know this pinner personally so there's no way to ask them to repin with a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

This seems slightly unorthodox, but you could reassign the location.hash. At the top of the page, you can try this - it seemed to work in my tests. Of course, you can also find any non alpha characters at the beginning and strip them. I am just showing a base example.

```
window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace('.','');
```